# Ubuntu base 18.04 network doesn't work until you type dhclient

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

After installing ubuntu base 18.04 the interface is disabled and the internet doesn't work automatically, I have to run `dhclient` after which the network interface starts working
I have tried installing resolvconf

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

this doesn't seem to fix the issue either.

any suggestions?

Comment: Please update Your question with contents of the file `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

If it works perfectly well as long as you run `dhcclient` maybe you should just add that to the startup applications?

just type "startup" into the dash and gui allowing you to specify programs should be the first suggestion, then you can simply add `dhcclient`.

Answer (score 0):

You need netplan.io and NetworkManager packages, plus a configuration file to have the network automatically set up at boot time.

`apt install netplan.io network-manager`

```bsh
echo """network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
""" > /etc/netplan/01.yaml
```